# human-in-the-loop

Tags: phrase-meaning, terminology

Can someone help me understand with the short phase "human-in-the-loop"?

sample sentence

> I think the human-in-the-loop design pattern for how we manage a large set of ML pipelines at O'Reilly makes possible some of our use of AI applications that wouldn't be manageable otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Usual meaning of "human-in-the-loop":**

A feedback loop is a system used for making decisions.  For example:

- The driver of a car adjusts the steering wheel.
- The steering wheel changes the angle of the front wheels.
- The combination of how fast the car is going, the angle of the front wheels, and the tires' grip on the road changes the direction the car is going.
- Also, other forces on the car (like wind, the camber of the road, and engine torque) affect the direction the car is going.
- The driver notices how much the direction of the car has changed.
- Repeat until the journey is over.

This repeating process is a "loop".  If the driver is a human, there is a "human in the loop".  If the driver is a completely automatic robot, then there is not a "human in the loop".

**"Human in the Loop" as the name of a "Design Pattern":**

The example in the original post is slightly different.  It is using the phrase "human-in-the-loop" as the name of a "[design pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?DesignPatterns)".  A design pattern is a medium- or high-level software engineering concept.  "It describes [a recurring] problem, [a general] solution, when to apply the solution, and its consequences. It also gives implementation hints and examples."

This particular design pattern has been discussed [elsewhere](https://lukasbiewald.com/2017/02/14/artificial-intelligence-and-the-future-of-work/):  Have a computer make the decisions it can make confidently, and ask a human to help with decisions that the computer is not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

Human in the loop (HITL) is a term for human interaction in technology such as ML(machine learning) and flight simulators.